# Django Error from views when submitting Comment Button

Tags: django, django-views

Helloo,

I have created a comment button for my blog posts and I am getting "This page isn’t working" after submitting the comment button and I don't know the reason.

I can add comments from the admin but can not submit as a user from website

I am not sure what needs to be changed in the views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-id')
        total_likes = post.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                content = self.request.POST.get('content')
                comment = Comment.objects.create(
                    post=post, user=request.user, content=content)
                comment.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        context["comments"] = comments
        context["comment_form"] = comment_form
        return context


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "score.html"
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5
```

here is the template

```
            <form method="post" class="comment-form" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ comment_form.as_p }}
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
            {% else %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" disabled> You must be Logged in to Comment
            {% endif %}
            </form>
```

here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='liked')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=120)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if not self.slug:
             self.slug = slugify(self.title)
         super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("score:post-detail", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # reply = models.ForeignKey('Comment', null=True, related_name="replies")
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.post.title, str(self.user.username))
```

Comment: hi please add your models and post_detail.html (completely) to the post, thanks

Comment: @Hmdbbgh I added it in the question

Comment: OK, tanks, i test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using parent class `DetailView` for your PostDetailView. However, there is no post method defined in [`DetailView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/33c365781abbcc1b21a31b31d95d344a174df0d5/django/views/generic/detail.py#L103). I believe when you submit your comment you are getting `HTTP 405 method not allowed`. You can check it from browsers developer tools.

I advice you to use a separate view for saving your comments.

```py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-id')
        total_likes = post.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        comment_form = CommentForm()

        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        context["comments"] = comments
        context["comment_form"] = comment_form
        return context

class PostCommentCreateView(CreateView):
       model = Comment
       fields = ['content']

       def get(self, request, post_id, *args, **kwargs):
           raise Http404

       def post(self, request, post_id, *args, **kwargs):
           self.post = Post.objects.get_or_404(id=post_id)
           self.user = request.user

           super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.post = self.post
            form.instance.user = self.user
            return super(StudentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

You need to provide action to your form:

```html
            <form action={% url 'post-comment' Post.id %} method="post" class="comment-form" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ comment_form.as_p }}
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
            {% else %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" disabled> You must be Logged in to Comment
            {% endif %}
            </form>
```

To make your create view to work you need to add the following line to your urls:

```py
    path('post/<int:post_id>/comment', views.PostCommentCreateView.as_view(), name='post-comment'),
```

you need to add new url for the comment page with the `post-comment` name as well. And some additional imports.

Comment: I added url and I think i am getting closer but i am getting ` post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post_id' ` error

Comment: Your url need an argument, if you add an argument named post_id it will be working

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a total_likes() method in Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ...

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.all().count()
```

Alternatively, you can change the view:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        total_likes = post.likes.all().count()
        # ...
```